# Why can't I scp a file to this host while I can ssh to it?

Tags: ssh, ip, scp, openssh, ipv6

I configured sshd on my remote host with `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/custom.conf`:

```
AddressFamily inet6
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication no
Match Address fe80::d075:6982:4410:e071
```

This is a fresh installation of openssh-server on my host's Ubuntu LTS, I haven't changed anything
in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. `ip l` on my remote host returns:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:60:24:be:5c:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:42:a6:15:fa:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0
```

but I when I use my host's wireless interface as the optional parameter after `%` then
I cannot ssh into it, both the following commands:

```
ssh -6 root@fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlo1
ssh -6 root@fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlp3s0
```

return these errors respectively:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlo1: Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlp3s0: Name or service not known
```

I can ssh to the host when specifying my wireless interface on my local host, `ssh -6 root@fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlp4s0` but I cannot scp a file,
`scp -6 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlp4s0:~` returns

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fe80: Temporary failure in name resolution
lost connection
```

I've tried wrapping the address along with the interface, like so `scp -6 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@[fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlp4s0]:~` in braces but to no avail.
`fe80::cc08:9465:8dba:15a9%wlp4s0` is reacheable with `ping`.
Both hosts are on the same, wireless LAN  and have Ubuntu LTS Desktops, 22.04 as their operating systems. I've opened port 22 on the remote host - `ufw status` on the remote host returns

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       fe80::d075:6982:4410:e071
```

What is happening here?

1. Why can't I ssh specifying target's interface instead of my own?
2. I can ssh to the remote host from my local host, why can´t I scp a file into it?
3. Where could I read more on the notation used for optionally specifying the interface (Chat GPT3.5 suggested using it as I was not able to connect with just bare IP)? Ctrl-F `%` on https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1, or on `man ssh` returns nothing.

Comment: The square brackets seem like the right approach, yet for that you gave us only vague *"to no avail"* instead of an actual error.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You are right. Square brackets work fine. I had a typo around those square braces that I have not noticed before - my bad. That's why I was thinking they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I ssh specifying target's interface instead of my own?

Link local addresses are all in exactly the same CIDR range for every device in the world.

The reason that the interface needs to be specified is that the OS needs to know where to route the request.  Normally the CIDR range of the IP address would tell the OS which interface to use by way of the routing table, but since link local addresses are all in the same range, this can't work and you need to explicitly tell the OS which interface to send the request from.